# Expression language not parsed after upgrade 7

Tags: spring, tomcat, el

We have upgraded from Tomcat6 to tomcat 7 and without doing any pom changes, facing problems in parsing of regular expression.
We build the listing screen dynamically and have some customization to create various components.
One of them is the value of radio tag which gets created and parsed at runtime.

```
<input id="selectedId3" name="selectedId" type="radio" value="${filterGrid_rowNum-1}"/>
```

This should have been parsed as below at server but is not happening

```
<input id="selectedId3" name="selectedId" type="radio" value="2"/>
```

Then we upgraded to servlet2.2, changed web.xml but it does not solve problem.
We are using Spring webflow,Jstl 2.0.
Not sure what is going on but the biggest change I see is el 2.2 in tomcat 7.

Any pointers ?

Comment: When you say "not happening", what actually gets rendered? The plain EL text? Nothing? Is this specific to complex EL expressions (ie, do plain EL values render fine)?

Comment: Yes it is only complex EL expressions that are not getting rendered. The value gets rendered as value="${filterGrid_rowNum-1}".

Comment: Does your complex expression work in a `c:out` element? Complex expressions *only* being affected makes me wonder, tho. EL should throw an error if it can't parse an expression.